# How to run "npm start" within eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, npm-start

I have a ReactJS application with dependencies managed by npm. I use eclipse as an IDE. My application runs using "npm start" command. To execute "npm start" command, I need to open terminal window and run it there. I would like to run this command from within eclipse. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Probably way too late to answer this but you can use `ctrl + alt + shift + t` to open up any command line tools installed.

[image: local terminal on selection]

Answer (score 1):

Install Nodeclipse.
Right click 'package.json' -> Run As 'npm ...' -> Write the goal 'start' and run it

Comment: I get only "npm install" and "npm update" options. Which plugin do you have?

Comment: Sorry, i forget. Nodeclipse